# XCode: Interface Builder crashes while compiling XIB

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, ios-simulator, xcodebuild, ibtool

When i compile my app with the command line tool `xcodebuild` (XCode 4.2.1 - iOS SDK 5.0) randomly the `ibtoold` (Interface Builder) crashes. When i rerun the build everything works fine.

The following error happens:

```
ibtoold[88134:107] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-933/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:499
 Details:  Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator. If you choose to file a crash report or radar for this issue, please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" and include their content in your crash report.
Exception name: NSInvalidReceivePortException
Exception reason: connection went invalid while waiting for a reply because a mach port died
Exception backtrace: 
(null)
Exception info:(null)
Object:   <IBAssertionShim: 0x40047fac0>
Method:   -reportMarshallingFailure:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40010a220>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
   0  0x00000001068f42d4 -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
   1  0x00000001068f41a4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
   2  0x00000001094f1e20 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
   3  0x0000000109572081 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
   4  0x00000001095720d4 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
   5  0x0000000106087d25 (in ibtoold)
   6  0x0000000106085413 (in ibtoold)
   7  0x0000000106085120 (in ibtoold)
   8  0x000000010608502c (in ibtoold)
   9  0x000000010608ed56 (in ibtoold)
  10  0x0000000106084baa (in ibtoold)
  11  0x0000000106085b8f (in ibtoold)
  12  0x0000000106083644 (in ibtoold)
 Command /Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Exactly the same happens to me. Have you found solution?

Comment: Not yet, filled a bug to Apple...

Comment: Seems that this issue is hopefully fixed in Xcode 4.3.1 for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is seemingly a **bug** with **Xcode 4.2.***.

Try updating to 4.3 - it works for me.

Comment: I can from time to time see this issue when our build server builds a project for us (Using Xcode 4.3). Just retrying fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

This issue was reliably reproducible for one project I was working on.  Changing the order of the xib files in the target's "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase worked for me.